# Dr. Racket and R5RS Scheme: (current-directory) is not working

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to use R5RS, in Dr.Racket.  I want to know the directory in which  I am working and would like to change the directory.  When I try in  R5S5, I  get the following error:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.12 [3m].
Language: R5RS; memory limit: 128 MB.
> (current-directory)
. . current-directory: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier
>
```

However, running the same thing in Racket, I am getting the directory.

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.12 [3m].
Language: racket, with debugging; memory limit: 128 MB.
> (current-directory)
#<path:/home/shree/>
>
```

I am not able to find what is the  corresponding primitive for `current-directory` in **R5RS**.

Comment: Neither R5RS nor R6RS Scheme specify a procedure that does this; file system interfaces are mostly left to the implementations. In Chez Scheme (R6RS) you can use `current-directory`; in Guile Scheme (R5RS) you can use `getcwd`. Racket's R5RS doesn't have any of those sorts of extensions, so you will probably have to rely on other Racket libraries.

Comment: You might want to read about [the limitations of Racket's R5RS implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11363504/6879826).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can require stuff from Racket:

```
#lang r5rs

(#%require (only racket/base current-directory))
(display (current-directory))
```

Comment: But this makes the result being not r5rs Scheme! It will not be portable.